# Examples of materials with saturation magnetic flux densities over 8T

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science

We regularly hear about magnets breaking the highest flux density records produced by laboratories, obviously the magnetic field intensity is generally not stated, so are there any materials that have low reluctance ( similar to silicon steel at 0.6-1T) at such high flux densities as most ferromagnetic materials would saturate well before this limit is reached ?